# vi editor command :w! resulted in an empty file

Tags: rhel, vim

Today I was trying to make some changes in a `.json` file in Linux using vi editor. While saving the file I got the warning saying `cannot write to the backup file, use ! to override.` I then ran `:w!` command and it said that updates were saved. But when I did `cat [filename]`, the file was empty.

Later I realized I was getting the warning in vim because system storage was full. I freed up some space. I then ran `vi -r [filename]` as well to recover the file but it says `No swap file found for [filename].`

There are 5 files additionally created with extensions `.json~`, `.jsox~`, `.jsoy~`, `.jsoz~`, `.jsov~` all being empty.

Is there a way to recover the file as it was an important one?

Comment: From your most recent backup (or snapshot)?

Comment: Is there a default directory where vi stores it's backup?

Comment: `vi` doesn't make backups. Systems administrators do.

Comment: "it said that updates were saved": what exactly did it say? It sounds like it never wrote anything at all.

Answer (score 0):

When you got the message saying “cannot write to the backup file,” that meant that those files you wrote (e.g., `json~`) were going to be empty.  In addition, if you had the swap file set up, because the disk was full, there'd be no way to write to it, and therefore `vim -r` wouldn't be effective.  (Swap files may or may not actually have been enabled.)

So unless you have a set of backups, you're unlikely to be able to recover your data.